# How to set same cache folder for different spiders, now scrapy creates subfolder in cache dir for each spider

Tags: python, caching, scrapy, web-crawler, directory

I have spiders running on same domain, second spiders run depends on results of first spider, and I would like they share cache information, but in cache folder they create subfolders with spiders names, is that possible to set same folder for them? Maybe scrapy has cache, that don't use different folders for different spiders (and support compressing like 'scrapy.extensions.httpcache.FilesystemCacheStorage'? Looks like levelDB and DBM also uses spider names for some soft of "subfoldering")

Also, if I somehow do so, presumable by removing spider.name in os.path join in httpcache.py for FilesystemCacheStorage (or change it to scrapy project name):

```
    def _get_request_path(self, spider, request):
        key = request_fingerprint(request)
        return os.path.join(self.cachedir, spider.name, key[0:2], key)
```

would not any meta/spider specific information will prevent them from reuse cache info?

Long read version (maybe I have bad approach at all): or maybe I do it all wrong and for multiple runs on some intersections of links from domain I should consider use pipeline?
I scrape:

menu_1/subelements_1/subelements_1_2/items_set_1 in spider1

and then

menu_2/subelements_2/subelements_2_2/items_set_2 in spider2,

but items_set_1 have interconnection with about 40% of items_set_2 (i.e. same items, like universal_item_id are same) and in this case I don't need them (items from items_set_1)  in items_set_2, and I can found out that I don't need this item in spider2, cause spider1 has this data, only when I finally get item, so I've got folder with 300mb gzipped cache data for spider1, and gzipped cache data for spider2 (and I like: "oh, we have this universal_item_id in items_set_1, so we don't yield this item in spider2") , from which ~40% of space I downloaded twice. Cause they cached in different subfolders.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try to just subclass `scrapy.extensions.httpcache.FilesystemCacheStorage` and override the `_get_request_path` to use a single folder (see an example here https://github.com/scrapy-plugins/scrapy-splash/blob/master/scrapy_splash/cache.py). Default cache request fingerprint does not take meta into consideration, only url/body/method and I believe headers but only if configured to do so, not by default.

Don't forget to specify your class in `HTTPCACHE_STORAGE` config.